# Is it possible to maintain state between Postgres trigger invocations?

Tags: python, postgresql, plpython

I am implementing a trigger in PostgreSQL using Python that
sends an AMQP message via amqpy.

A connection is required to send the message.  Currently,
the only way I know to do this is, when the trigger is
invoked, open a connection, send the message, and close the
connection.

I would like to not have to keep opening a new connection
for every trigger invocation.  Is there a way to initialize
the connection once, and then make it available to future
trigger invocations?

There would also have to be a way to detect if the connection
went down and re-establish it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can share data between pl/python functions.

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/plpython-sharing.html

It should be possible to open a connection, stash it in "GD" and reuse it. Don't know if AMPQ needs a clean close on its connection though.

Comment: That is precisely the functionality I was looking for.  Many thanks!

Comment: And no, AMQP does not need a clean close.